# Can the DJI fpv remote be used with a 2nd radio in a buddybox setup?

Tags: buddy-box, dji-air-unit

I’m trying to introduce my children to fpv. It would be great if there was a way to setup a buddybox that used DJI’s remote as either master or slave. I only have the DJI remote currently, so it would be a bummer to need 2 new radios to accomplish this.

If DJI was the slave I realize I’d need to use a different receiver, I have some old R-XSRs I can use.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://intofpv.com/t-buddy-box-for-dji-fpv) thread, the answer is that the DJI FPV system doesn’t natively support BuddyBox.

However, they do mention that you may be able to use an R-XSR, and feed the SBUS output of the Air Unit into the SBUS in pad to use it as a backup receiver.